# SQL Agent Job History

Tags: sql-server

I'm using the `msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory` to get the history of each step that has executed in each package which is I believe the same query executed if doing a view history on the right click of the job.

My problem is there doesn't seem to be any way of tying a run of a job together. E.g.

[image: This is the output of the query]

What I need to do is tie it up like it does in the UI to each run of the job:

[image: as such]

Answer (score 0):

Use sysjobs, sysjobhistory, sysjobactivity, and sysjobschedules (all found in the msdb database). You can tie everything together using job_id.

Comment: But the Job_Id is the same everytime it runs. So you would end up with a Cartesian join